# What distinguishes measure theory and probability theory?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, soft-question

It is clear that the theory of probability works primarily with limited measures on measurable spaces. On the other hand, there is a folklore that says that what distinguishes measure theory and probability theory is the conditional probability and conditional expectation.

But conditional probabilities and conditional expectations are derived from the [Radon–Nikodym theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem) and a measure with respect to another measure. And the Radon–Nikodym theorem is a typical result of measure theory.

> **Question 1:** So we could see the theory of probability as a subdiscipline of measure theory?

> **Question 2:** Would be possible to give another basis for the theory of probability rather than through measure theory?

Comment: Measure theory allows unbounded measures.  There exists a uniform measure on the integers, for example, but there is no uniform probability.

Comment: There is a discussion of what distinguishes probability theory from measure theory in [section 10.2](http://books.google.com/books?id=_9xWBlvUEuIC&pg=PA172) of Loève's book *Probability Theory I*.

Comment: Saying that probability is a subdiscipline of measure theory is like saying that mathematics is subdisciple of logic.

Comment: Measure theory is a tool people use, probability theory is a field of mathematics.

Comment: "Probability theory is measure theory with soul".

Comment: Mikhael Gromov - 1/6 Probability, symmetry, linearity. Possible directions of modification/generalization of the probability theory. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aJAQVletzdY

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would say that conditioning and independence is something that disctinct, expectation is used a lot in the measure theory as well, by the name of the Lebesgue integral.

The point is that the probability as a science before was maybe even more closer to physics than to math by being based on experiments. It became the classical Probability *Theory* (PT) when it was [axiomatized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms) the first half of XX century by the means of Measure Theory (MT). So MT is clearly a mathematical basis for the classical PT and in that sense you can consider PT to be a subdiscipline of MT.

There are two moments to mention, though.

1. There is an [algebraic approach to probability](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/02/10/245a-notes-5-free-probability/) which starts with algebras of random variables and defines a linear functional on such algebras - which is an expectation. Shall we say that the Probability Theory is a subdiscipline of Abstract Algebra?
2. In both cases - you start with something empirical: probability, random variables etc. You wish them to satisfy some kind of properties and by this you bring a particular structure: either a measure-theoretical, or an algebraic. However, there is an additional meaning of the results that you obtain.  For example, the [Law of Large Numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers) and [Central Limit Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) are obtained by using pure measure-theoretical methods. But these results are very important exactly for Probability Theory. The interpretation of MT via probabilistic ideas provides you additional intuition about "how should it be" and help to understand "what does it mean".

That is completely an opinion which I've chosen for myself. Hope that it helps.

Comment: That's really interesting. @Ilya have you got any good reference about this algebraic presentation of Probability Theory?

Comment: @ineff: I didn't work with it - just read [this note in Terence Tao's blog](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/02/10/245a-notes-5-free-probability/). That's quite enough to have a first impression

Comment: @Ilya. I appreciate your response. The algebra that differs from the analysis (and particularly the theory of measure) is the axiom of the supreme. Although I am not sure I believe this can be an algebraic basis for the Theory of Probability. But it's like I said. I'm not sure.

Comment: At the moment I'm reading theTerence Tao blog post that you've indicated. I'm thinking interessande. But English is not my native language so it takes me to read. Thank you.

Comment: This [other note](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/01/254a-notes-0-a-review-of-probability-theory/) (linked from the note already posted) gives a lot of discussion about the difference in philosophy between probability and measure theory.

Comment: Probability was an area of mathematics (rather than physics) before its foundations were secure.  The same was true of calculus and complex numbers and even geometry.

Comment: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2020/10/04/foundational-aspects-of-uncountable-measure-theory-gelfand-duality-riesz-representation-canonical-models-and-canonical-disintegration/ could be thought of as along similar lines of item 1, now with an emphasis on categorical formalism.

Answer (score 6):

Salomon Bochner's words in the introduction to his article entitled 'Stochastic Processes' published in 1947 in volume 48 of the Annals of Matematics:

[image]

The link to [full text.](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1969392?origin=crossref)

Answer (score 3):

In the words of David Williams in his book [*Probability with Martingales*](https://www.cambridge.org/highereducation/books/probability-with-martingales/B4CFCE0D08930FB46C6E93E775503926#overview) (page xi):

> Measure theory for its own sake is based on the fundamental addition rule for measures. Probability theory supplements that with the multiplication rule which describes independence; and things are already looking up. But what really enriches and enlivens things is that we deal with lots of $\sigma$-algebras, not just the one $\sigma$-algebra which is the concern of measure theory.

Answer (score 1):

I'd also add to the answers above that the 0-1 laws also contribute to giving probability it's own flavour separate from standard measure theory. Kolmogorov's 0-1 law coupled with the notation of independence give consequences like the law of the iterated logarithm. This math overflow post discusses other situations in which, despite the 0-1 law implying that certain probabilities are 0 or 1, it is hard to tell which it is! I don't think similar questions arise in measure theory.

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/2904/examples-where-kolmogorovs-zero-one-law-gives-probability-0-or-1-but-hard-to-de